# Schedule tasks for later

Tags: android

### What I have :

An application with two tabs, one for *upcoming deliveries* and one for *past deliveries*.
I fetch the upcoming deliveries in a SQLite database where validity date is upper than current date and vice-versa for past deliveries (update ui of the two list).

### What I want :

Each deliveries has a validity date, and if a delivery pass his validity date, I would like that it go in the *past delivery* tab.

---

**Further information :**

- The two tabs are added with a `ViewPager` which contains for each a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView`.
- These deliveries are added by myself (by a `FloatingActionButton`), there is no webservices.
- Scope of SDK Version is 17 to 28

---

Is there an utility class in android sdk (or java) to achieve this kind of job ?

Comment: I have found `JobScheduler` (*api >= __21__*) & `AlarmManager` (*api < __21__*) but I never used them before and not quit sure if this do the job ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PART 1

---

IF scheduling a job that works in the background to update your table etc, is what you want, below is the answer :

My Suggestion is to use the  'Android-Job' library by EverNote. 
This library does the same thing as both 'JobScheduler' and 'AlarmManager', but AndroidJobs library will take care of API version issues for you, so you can just configure when your task should be executed.
ie. InternetAvailable = true , interval = 5 mins &  charging =true etc(this is pseudocode, but it's similar to their api)

Their api is easy to use and lets you schedule a task without having to worry about SDK versions and using multiple Android APIs to do the same thing.

Here is the gitHub link :https://github.com/evernote/android-job

### PART2

---

> Each deliveries has a validity date, and if a delivery pass his
>   validity date, I would like that it go in the past delivery tab.

IF you want to just update the UI and not change anything in the table, you don't need a scheduled task, done using scheduler and Alarm Manager (or Android-Job library).

What you can do is have a handler thread inside your Activity, that executes every 5 seconds(you can change the time).

In the code below, the activity with the tabs, start a Handler task that runs ever 5 seconds and inside the when the task runs, it tells your fragments to check it's data. So each fragment can now check every 5 seconds if the data they have is correct and redraw.

EG :

```
import android.os.Handler;
MyActivity extends Activity {

  private UpcomingDeliverFragment UpcomingFragment;
  private PastDeliverFragment pastFragment;

  private Handler handler = new Handler()

  private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            UpcomingFragment.checkDataSet();
            pastFragment.checkDataSet();
            startHandler(); // so the task runs again after 5 secs
    }
  };

  private onResume() {
   startHandler();
  }

  private onPause() {
   stopHandler(); // very important
  }


   private fun startHandler() {
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
   }      

   private fun stopHandler() {
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will keep in mind 'Android-Job' library !
I was already considering how use alternatively `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager` depending on API level.

Comment: I've already considered to use an Handler, but when I mentioned this eventuality I was told that, this will do to many work/use of the database.

Comment: Can we do something like that : Each item (*delivery*) created, add a background task with the item reference and its "Date". In that way I can update the whole list or just remove/add the referenced item. It will give me the possibility to add a notification to the user too ?

Comment: you can do what you mentioned, but if I understand correctly, you will be creating one background task for each list items, so if you have 50 list items, you have 50 background tasks!!! Now, you can do couple of things, you can maintain a collection of items in the activity or fragment and every x seconds, go iterate the list and check if anything needs to be removed, as this is in memory, it should be real quick. PS: You are trying to solve multiple issues in one question, my suggestion is to break out your problem into multiple smaller problems and solve/ask each question separately.

Comment: Yeah I agree... it will be awful !
I will dig into these considerations.
Thx again :)